# Unable to get list items correct code using Java

Tags: java, list, android-listview

I am trying to create a list view in Java that allows each list item to open a web url address but I can not seem to get the code right. Please can some one show me where IO going wrong.

```
package com.sasquatchapps.hydraquip10.bestofmonsterquest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Season1Activity extends Activity{

    private String episodes[] = {"America's Loch Ness Monster","Sasquatch Attack",
            "Giant Squid Found","Birdzilla","Bigfoot","“Mutant K9","Lions in the Backyard","Gigantic Killer Fish","Swamp Beast","Russia's Killer Apemen","Unidentified Flying Creatures","The Real Hobbit",
            "Giganto: The Real King Kong","American Werewolf"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new
                ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, episodes);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item clicked;" + episodes[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (position == 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7-RdxrCFAg"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate the error you are getting. I think you might get compile time error because you are extending Activity. Not ListActivity and trying to call setListAdapter method. seContentView(int) also not called.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors - Where is your `listview`? Modify your code

1) create listview -

```
ListView myList;
```

2) In your onCreate assign this list:

```
myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
```

3) Set adapter to your list:

```
 myList.setAdapter(adapter);
```